# How to change the object value in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an array of objects, and I am just trying to change the object value, but I am getting the error "Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'".

```
 interface Field {
 _id: string;
 name: string;
 title: string;
 required: boolean;
 }

 const fields: Field[] = [{ _id: "", name: "", title: "", required: 
 false }];

 function handleChangeField(
    index: number,
    key: string,
    value: string | boolean
  ) {
    fields[index][key as keyof Field] = value; //Error
  }


 handleChangeField(0, "required", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Typescript is inferring type from your array decleration of empty array.
To fix this you just need to declerare your array like

```
const fields: Field[]= [];
```

Reason you are getting error  cannot be assigned to never is because typescript doesnt know if you key is `required` or other keys which are of type string.

To fix that you can either declerare types in your function parameters as mentioned by @iz_

```
function handleChangeField<K extends keyof Field>(
    index: number,
    key: K,
    value: Field[K]
) {
    fields[index][key] = value;
}
```

or you could also handle explicit type check in your function -

```
 function handleChangeField(
    index: number,
    key: keyof Field,
    value: string | boolean
  ) {
      if (key === "required") {
          fields[index][key] = (value as boolean);
      } else {
          fields[index][key] = (value as string);
      }
  }
```

Comment: I just forget to put it in my example, but I have it in my source code, and it still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the function generic on the key because your interface has more than one type of value:

```
interface Field {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    title: string;
    required: boolean;
}

const fields: Field[] = [{ _id: "", name: "", title: "", required: false }];

function handleChangeField<K extends keyof Field>(
    index: number,
    key: K,
    value: Field[K]
) {
    fields[index][key] = value;
}


handleChangeField(0, "required", true);
```